# OpenLayers Map redraws tiles every time it pans or zooms (Custom XYZ Tile Layer)

Tags: openlayers

Something is causing the layer tiles to be discarded and re-fetched every time the map is panned.

In `OpenLayers.Layer.Grid.moveTo`, it checks the current tile bounds and decides whether to re-use existing tiles (via `moveGriddedTiles`) or fetch them all from scratch (via `initGriddedTiles`).  Since the tile bounds are incorrect (they sometimes appear to be in degrees, and sometimes look like they've been transformed in the wrong direction - around 0.0015...).

Does anyone have any clues about where to start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with `transform()`ing the bounds in my custom getURL function, **and forgetting to `clone()` them first**.

```js
this.layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ(
    'layer description',
    myBaseUrl + '&x=${x}&y=${y}&z=${z}',
    {
        name: 'layer name',
        getURL: getMyTileUrl,
        type: 'jpg',
        minZoomLevel: 15,
        maxZoomLevel: 18,
        isBaseLayer: false,
        transitionEffect: 'resize',
        buffer: 3
    }
);

function getMyTileUrl(bounds) {
    bounds = bounds.transform(this.projection,"EPSG:4326");
    // ...
    return this.url + z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type;
}
```

The solution was simply cloning the bounds before transforming them.

```
function getMyTileUrl(bounds) {
    bounds = bounds.clone().transform(this.projection,"EPSG:4326");
    // ...
    return this.url + z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type;
}
```

Forgetting to clone the bounds meant that I was transforming the "official" bounds object for that tile.  The next time this bounds object is used is to determine whether the currently-loaded tiles intersect with the new map bounds, to determine whether we should move some tiles or throw them all away and fetch new ones.  Since they were transformed into a different projection, OpenLayers thought the currently-loaded tiles were from a totally different part of the planet, so it threw them all away and started over.